context.pop() dialogs after migrating to go_router 13.2.3 from <13
I just migrated my go_router package from 12.1.3 to 13.2.4.
I checked the breaking changes but could not find anything about pop. Currently I extended my context with this:
extension HelperExtensions on BuildContext {
  void maybePop<T extends Object?>([T? result]) {
    if (canPop()) {
      return pop(result);
    }
  }
}

But when using this in dialogs, it will not pop them, but instead pop the view beneath them. When I do Navigator.of(this, rootNavigator: true).pop() it works.
Can someone explain me why this is the case? Why are dialogs not anymore on the navigators page stack?
Is using rootNavigator instead now correct? What does canPop() even do then. Does it still check the correct thing when I afterwards use Navigator.of(this, rootNavigator: true).pop() to pop my dialog?
Thanks a lot.
Edit
In fact I just want to have a method I can call when I want to pop the top most pushed page/dialog. And it should first check if there is something to pop. Because it could happen that it is called even though there is only one thing on the stack.

have you found a better solution on this in dismissing the dialog using Navigator.of(this, rootNavigator: true).pop() kinda out of place when using it

@ArbiterChil nope. That is why I ask here :D

I created a POC using your extension and it worked properly. It might be something related to your routes or how you are handling your dialog.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => Page1(),
    )
  ],
);

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => Center(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text('DIALOG'),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => context.maybePop(),
                      child: Text('Close'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text('Open Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'My App',
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

extension HelperExtensions on BuildContext {
  void maybePop<T extends Object?>([T? result]) {
    if (canPop()) {
      return pop(result);
    }
  }
}

